# Unable to encrypt and digitally sign in Thunderbird

Tags: encryption

How do I get

1. a digital signing certificate and
2. a certificate to encrypt/decrypt both in Thunderbird?

I have `gnupg2` and `enigmail` installed but i am still unable to generate these certificates.

Comment: Do you want to use S/MIME or PGP to encrypt and sign mail?

Comment: S/MIME unless PGP is much easier to use thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get a certificate. Comodo hands out free certs [here](https://www.comodo.com/home/email-security/free-email-certificate.php). I can't vouch for their reliability or acceptance, but it's an way to get a cert.
2. Download your certificate files, or follow instructions from the key provider.
3. These will initially have to be added to the same browser as you used to generat the key. In firefox (which works, chrome did not want to generate keys for me), go to Prefcerences - advanced - Certificates - View Certificates and Your Certificates. Import the file you have from your Comodo (Note: If you're using different service, the procedure may differ!).
4. Select the imported certificate and back it up. You can use a blank password if you want:

[image: Backup cert]

1. Open Thunderbird, and go to Account settings - Security:

[image: Thunderbird Settings - Security]

1. Select Manage Certificates, and Your Certificates:
   [image: Manage certificates.]
2. This will add it to the certificate store. Press OK.
3. Select a digital signing certificate:
   [image: Digital signing certificate]
4. You will be asked if you want to use the same certificate for encrypting and decrypting messages as well. Answer yes.

That's it. Now you can send encrypted e-mails to people, if you have their S/MIME certificate.

Note that the real pain here, which I have not touched upon, is getting the other users certificate. In this regard PGP is actually easier to use in my opinion, as there is a a rather well defined network of keyservers.

If you want to test it, I'll leave my e-mail address in a comment so you can send me an encrypted mail.

Comment: and if you want to test - se(at)bitsex.net should work :)

Comment: Many thanks. I tried Comodo but it said "your browser (firefox) did not send the request" as if Firefox blocked the request for certs.

Comment: Chrome had this problem for me. Firefox 52 ESR worked.

Comment: I finally got the cert from Comodo thanks. I tried to email you Vidarlo but it said I needed your certificate. May be PGP is a better option? How do I set that up? Thanks. N

Comment: Send me a signed, unencrypted, e-mail - that way I should get your certificate.